# Authentication error pymongo through docker

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, server, pymongo

I'm trying to connect to a database inside a docker container and it, in turn, inside a remote server from my home computer. The docker container port `27017` is binded to port `27017` of the server machine.

Now, I have a Python3 script whose aim is connect to this database from my home computer:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client=MongoClient('mongodb://myserverusername:myserverpass@server.dir.com:27017')
database=client["my_collection"]
cursor=database["my_collection"].find({})
print(next(cursor))
```

If I execute my script stopping in `line 4`, it works fine, but when I unleash `line 5`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testDatabase.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(next(cursor))
  File "[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1132, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1055, in _refresh
    self.__collation))
  File "[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 892, in __send_message
    **kwargs)
  File "[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 950, in _send_message_with_response
    exhaust)
  File "[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 961, in _reset_on_error
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/server.py", line 99, in send_message_with_response
    with self.get_socket(all_credentials, exhaust) as sock_info:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/server.py", line 168, in get_socket
    with self.pool.get_socket(all_credentials, checkout) as sock_info:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 852, in get_socket
    sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)
  File "[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 570, in check_auth
    auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
  File "[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 486, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 466, in _authenticate_default
    return _authenticate_scram_sha1(credentials, sock_info)
  File "[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 209, in _authenticate_scram_sha1
    res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
  File "[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 477, in command
    collation=collation)
  File "[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 116, in command
    parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)
  File "[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 210, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thans in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question, if anyone have the same problem!

First of all, you need to connect to server via `ssh`, so, you must import `SSHTunnelForwarder` from `sshtunnel` and, of course, `pymongo`.

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import pymongo
```

Next, fix your parameters for, in one hand, server connection and, in the other hand, for `mongodb` connection

```
SERVER_HOST = "your.server.host.com"
SERVER_USER = "yourserverusername"
SERVER_PASS = "yourseverpassword"
MONGO_DB = "your_database_name"
MONGO_PORT = 27017
```

Now you must log into server through `ssh`.

```
ssh_connection = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    SERVER_HOST,
    ssh_username=SERVER_USER,
    ssh_password=SERVER_PASS,
    remote_bind_address=("localhost", MONGO_PORT) #localhost:27017 is mongodb url into server 
)

ssh_connection.start() #Start connection, you now are connected to server via ssh.
```

Once connected via `ssh`, you must create connection to `mongodb` into docker. It worth say that, although `27017` port in server is binded to `27017` port in docker container, it remains to bind one of your home machine port to `27017` server port. The object `ssh_connection` gives you a local port that binds the port you fulfilled as `MONGO_PORT` in `remote_bind_address` argument of `ssh_connection`. This allow you to unlock all the way to `mongodb` address into docker.

```
print(ssh_connection.local_bind_port) #When you start, mongodb is assigned to a local port for this connection, so this is the port you must use 
client = pymongo.MongoClient('127.0.0.1:{}'.format(ssh_connection.local_bind_port))
```

Now, you can do wherever you want with database. In this case, I perform a similar behavior of original post's example.

```
db = client[MONGO_DB]
cursor=db[MONGO_DB].find({})
for r in cursor:
    print(r)
print(cursor.count())
```

Once you finish all your tasks into database, you must close `ssh` session.

```
ssh_connection.stop() #End ssh connection
```

That's all folks!